# How to position a borderless form under buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created 4 buttons dynamically and placed them horizontally using c# win forms.Now i want show a custom tooltip(actually its a borderless form) under each of the 4 buttons on mouse hover event.But how do i position my tooltip form under the buttons??
I have tried the code below but it does not work the desired way.

```
tooltip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(b.Left, b.Top);
```

Where 'tooltip' is tooltip form object & 'b' is the dynamic button.Please advise with some code snippet.

```
private void B_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = sender as Button;
        //MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.ToString());
        if(b!= null)
        {
            if (tooltip == null)
            {
                tooltip = new frmSecQStatToolTipDlg();
            }

            tooltip.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(b.Left, b.Bottom);
            tooltip.data(b.Tag.ToString());
            tooltip.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "but it does not work the desired way" - what happens? Also, why `b.Top` when you want the bottom?

Comment: the tooltip pops up just wherever it feels like to..

Comment: even if i hardcode X=50 Y=50, the tooltip does not pop up at (50,50)

Comment: You need to show more of the code. What happens in the tooltip constructor? Are you setting `StartPosition` to `Manual` properly, etc.?

Comment: Currently StartPosition is set to WindowsDefaultLocation

Comment: So setting the `Location` before the form is visible will have no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you named it is a bit misleading. As I understand, what you call a tooltip is just a `Form`. You need to consider 2 things

(1) [Form.StartPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(v=vs.110).aspx) must be set to `FormStartPosition.Manual`

(2) `Form.Location` must be in **screen** coordinates. Note that the `Button.Location` you are trying to use is in button's parent client coordinates. [Control.PointToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has to be used for conversion.

In your case, it should be something like this

```
tooltip.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
var topLeft = b.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0)); 
tooltip.Location = new Point(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y + b.Height);
```

Comment: OMG! at last somebody has understood my requirement/problem correctly and has offered me the exact solution.Thanks @Ivan and and also other forum members for their codes and comments. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

When you show the tooltip you can control its location, check show method overloads: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx